# Get the value of my dropdownlist after an error of validation

Tags: laravel

I have 2 fields `sexe` and `adresse`, my variable `sexe` is a dropdownlist.

I select an item for example tha value `homme`. Then, the value of the adresse is `Rue du Lac 15`.

In my example, **the validation is wrong**...

[image]

Why, the item of my variable `sexe` is empty? Where is my value?

[image]

I don't understand where is my problem?

```
<fieldset class="form-group {{ $errors->has('sexe') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
  <label for="company-content">Sexe</label>
  <select name="sexe" id="sexe" class="form-control" required="required" value="{{ old('sexe')}}"/>
     <option value="">Choix sexe</option>
        <option>Femme</option>
        <option>Homme</option>
    {!! $errors->first('sexe', '<span class="help-block">:message</span>') !!}
  </select>
</fieldset>

<fieldset class="form-group {{ $errors->has('adresse') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
   <label for="form-group-input-1">Adresse</label>
   <input type="text" name="adresse" id="adresse" class="form-control" required="required" value="{{ old('adresse')}}"/>
   {!! $errors->first('adresse', '<span class="help-block">:message</span>') !!}
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `sexe` options don't have any `value`. Edit your code:

```
    <option value="femme">Femme</option>
    <option value="homme">Homme</option>
```

Comment: I always have the even problem... I don't get the value... :-(

Comment: If my answer helped, please mark it as correct answer for other people with same problem.